# validaciones (mayúsculas, minusculas)

Tags: python, validación, while

estoy empezando en python y necesito validar un input. Mi problema es el siguiente:

```
print("¡Bienveni@!\n")

print("Digite la figura que necesita para el calculo: \n\n-Triangulo \n-Cuadrado \n-Circulo \n- 
Trapecio ")

figura=input("\nla figura es: ")
```

Necesito que cuando la persona digite algo diferente a por ejemplo: "Cuadrado"
como podria ser "cuadrado" sin mayusculas me repita el codigo o si alguien sabe otro metodo me dicen :)

Comment: La idea básica es tener un booleano que indique si la respuesta fue correcta o no. Digamos que el booleano lo llamas `respuesta_ok`. Empezarías poniendo el valor `False`. Después harías un bucle `while not respuesta_ok:` y dentro metes la parte que pide la cadena. Después compruebas si la cadena es válida y en ese caso haces `respuesta_ok=True`. Ya que el bucle se repite mientras sea False, hasta que no dé una respuesta buena seguirá dentro del bucle y se le preguntará otra vez. Para mirar si la respuesta es correcta la comparas con cada una de las posiblidades, usando `or` entre comparaciones

Comment: Lo que comenta @abulafia es una mejora para tu codigo pero si quieres distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas sería un validación algo larga por lo que mejor es pasar todo a minúsculas con ```.lower()``` y haces la validación

Comment: @crhistian Pero yo entendí que precisamente tenía que rechazar "cuadrado" y admitir sólo "Cuadrado". Es un poco raro, sí, pero es lo que parece decir.

Comment: @abulafia si, es muy raro pero el profesor que me está ayudando aun siquiera nos pide una validación como tal porque es tema que no hemos visto y en el pdf dice que si es de nuestro gusto buscar como hacerlo que podemos hacer una validación que nos ayude solo a admitir que la persona digite las cosas tal y como pedimos, solamente es una tarea :)

Comment: @christian tomaré en cuenta el ".lower " :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capchris.p, una solución más sencilla para tu inconveniente es usar el método `capitalize`, que lo que hace es poner la letra mayúscula a la primera letra de una palabra. Por lo tanto, si en el input escribes `CUADRADO`, `cuadrado` o `CUadRAdo`, al imprimirse, el input siempre sale como `Cuadrado`.

```
print("¡Bienveni@!\n")

print("Digite la figura que necesita para el calculo: \n\n-Triangulo \n-Cuadrado \n-Circulo \n-Trapecio ")

figura = input("\nla figura es: ").capitalize()
print(figura)
```

Otra opción utilizar una lista vacía, para poder ingresar cualquier tipo de figura que se quiera utilizar. Y si alguna que uses no está en la lista, se agrega, y se use también el método `capitalize()`.

```
figuras = []

figura = input("Digite la figura que necesita para el calculo: ")

while figura not in figuras:
    figuras.append(figura.capitalize())
    break

print(figuras)
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @ariel berinstein. fuiste el que más claro me lo dejó y fue asi como me acabó funcionando :D

Comment: De nada @capchris.p. Me alegro mucho que te haya servido saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Una sugerencia a tu código para que sea más legible y eficiente podría ser lo siguiente:
Con esto ya no dependes de añadir las posibles respuestas ni la información que recibe el usuario, si no que puedes agregar a la lista 'figuras' la cantidad de figuras que desees.

```
figuras = ["triangulo", "cuadrado", "circulo", "trapecio"]

figura = ""

while figura not in figuras:
    figura = input(f"Escriba la figura que necesites para el calculo: {', '.join([i for i in figuras])}\n")
```